# Editing text in field editor disables ⌘S when menu item is customized

Tags: macos, nstextview, appkit

When I bind "File > Save ⌘S" to a custom `IBAction` it works fine, except when I use the window's field editor to make something editable programmatically. ([`NSTableHeaderCell`s, specifically.](https://christiantietze.de/posts/2016/04/edit-nstableview-header-cell/))

When the cursor is in any `NSTextField`, ⌘S is still activated.  That's what I want.

When the cursor is in the field editor (`NSText` based), ⌘S is deactivated. This only happens when I change the connection in `MainMenu.nib` to "First Responder > myCustomSaveMethod:".

Any ideas how to enable ⌘S-saving in the field editor in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happened is that the "First Responder" is anything above the current view in the responder chain. The manually invoked field editor is inserted into the responder chain below `NSWindowController`. `myCustomSaveMethod:` is implemented in a sub-view controller which is *not* part of that responder chain, so the method definition isn't available to the field editor.

Moving `myCustomSaveMethod:` to a responder in the chain that both the table view and the field editor share (e.g. the `NSWindowController`) works like a charm.
¯\_(ツ)_/¯